# Node.js callbacks and this - how it should be solved?

Tags: design, javascript, node.js

Every JavaScript programmer is familiar with `this` "problem" (it can be considered as a feature, depending on various conditions) - `this` is lately binded:

```
let foo = {
    bar(){return this;}
};
let _bar = foo.bar;
_bar() === foo.bar(); // false;
```

`_bar()` evaluates to global object or `undefined` depending on presence of `'use strict'` directive and `foo.bar()` evaluates to `foo`.

`Node.js` have a convention of providing "error first" callbacks.

My question is - what should be set by library as `this` of callback? `EventEmitter` instances set `this` to emitter instance and it would be most obvious solution for me - but I couldn't find popular libraries using this pattern.

Native `Array` instances methods use pattern `Array.prototype.method = function(fn, thisArg=null){}` with last argument being `this` context. It seems to be good solution for constant-length methods, but for variadic functions it have edge cases with `this` set to an instance of function.

Speaking outside of Node, jQuery use `$.ajax({context: thisArg})` to set `this` argument of callback.

So what would be the best solution for eg. class abstracting away implementation details of user?

```
User.getUserByLogin('nick', function(err, user) {
     // user is User instance
     user.updateUser({name: 'new name'}, function(err){
         // what SHOULD be `this` here?
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My general first recommendation about `this`, is don't use it, it makes programs harder to read with no real upside. The primary exception being constructor functions.

In a library you can just leave `this` of a callback being global/undefined, anything you would pass as a `this` value may as well be passed as another parameter.